# How to remove all folders named "Sample" from directory and subfolders?

Tags: batch-file, rmdir, delete-directory

I'm looking for a command line that I can add to a batch that I use.

Here's what I need to be able to do:

Lets say I have a directory:
C:\Users\username\Videos

With a subdirectories

C:\Users\username\Videos\test\sample
C:\Users\username\Videos\test2\sample

What command would I need to use to delete the sample folders in both subdirectories but not the test/test2 folders?

If you know of a way to use RMDIR that would be great but if not I'm open to ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command

```dos
dir /b /s /ad "C:\Users\username\Videos\sample"
```

will generate the list of folders to delete. Now, to process this list we wrap the command in a `for /f` command that will perform the directory removal command for each line in the output of the previous command

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('
        dir /b /s /ad "C:\Users\username\Videos\sample"
    ') do rd /s /q "%%a"
```

Or, to use it from command line

```dos
for /f "delims=" %a in ('dir /b /s /ad "C:\Users\username\Videos\sample"') do rd /s /q "%a"
```

In both cases, the `for /f` will iterate over the output lines of the `dir` command, storing the line in its replaceable parameter `%a` and executing the code after the `do` clause.

The default behaviour of `for` command is to *tokenize* the input lines splitting them using spaces and tabs as delimiters. To disable this behaviour
`delims=` clause is used: with no delimiters there is only one token containing the full line.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
for /f %i in ('dir /b/s/ad ^| findstr -I "\Sample$"') do rmdir %i
```

That does a recursive directory listing and filters for Sample directorues and then takes the list and deletes each one.  If you are going to put it in a batch file you need to double every % like this:

```
for /f %%i in ('dir /b/s/ad ^| findstr -I "\Sample$"') do rmdir %%i
```